# Which is best, make a multiple file or single file?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am about to start a new project with Flash Professional CS6 and AS3. My project is a huge one with a lot alot of MCs, coding, pictures ... etc. In a previous project with flash 8, I tried to use several files that were working with each others but I faced a lot of problems in loading and interacting with them. It was hard to control specially when it came to the loading stuff.

I don't know if any has been changed in CS6, But I want your advice. Should I use my old strategy by using many files? or should I dump all thing in one huge fla file?

In either case, what will be the best way to arrange the assets, codes, ... etc so they will be well organised and easy to work with in coding and yet give a high performance.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would go for one FLA file but with multiple (OOP) Classes to control it all.

Answer (score 0):

You should go with several source files, especially if your project is huge.
First of all, create dedicated .fla file for UI components and small/handmade elements, — *assets.fla* and compile it as assets.swc.

If you will compile project by the help of Flash Professional CS6 (but I would recommend some IDE...), you will have one more .fla file, *main.fla*, It's your entry point with Document Class, and connected libraries(mostly .swc files)

Images, huge animated scenes, all these stuff are external: Bitmaps, swf files you will load in runtime, and unload/dispose, for freeing memory.

Actually, It's an art to organise project, so It will be easily scaleable, and without problems you could work in team, and not interfere with each other

Comment: So I need at least three files: Main.fla, assets.fla (assets.swc), UI.fla and extra files will be out side any fla file. Is that right?, I did not understand the IDE thing, can you please provide me with extra info about it?

Comment: Main.fla and assets.fla (consists of UI components, graphic elements, animated elements and so on). But if you will select some [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) for working with ActionScript 3 project, you will be able to compile project without Flash Projessional, so you don't need Main.fla. Some great IDE for Flash development: FDT, FlashDevelop, Intellij Idea